# Algorithm improvement

Tags: c#, algorithm

My job-interview task was to:

*found one array item which satisfying condition: after you remove it, the multiplication of remaining items will be the highest.*
For instance: -5, -3, -1, 4, 6 => -1

My solution was recognized as non optimized enough.
Could you produce me with some suggestions on algorithm improvements?

**My solution was**:

```
public int FindRequiredValue(int[] IntArray)
    {
        try
        {
            Array.Sort(IntArray);

            var first = IntArray.First();
            var last = IntArray.Last();

            if (first >= 0)
                return first;
            else
                if (last < 0)
                    return (IsEven(IntArray.Count()) ? first : last);
                else
                {
                    if (last == 0)
                    {
                        var lastindex = IntArray.Count() - 1;
                        if (IntArray[lastindex - 1] == 0)
                            return first;
                        else
                            return IsEven(lastindex) ? 0 : first;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var firstpositiveindex = IntArray.Select((x, i) => new { element = x, index = i }).First(y => (y.element > 0)).index;

                        if (IntArray[firstpositiveindex - 1] < 0)
                            return IsEven(firstpositiveindex) ? IntArray[firstpositiveindex] : IntArray[firstpositiveindex - 1];
                        else
                            if (IntArray[firstpositiveindex - 2] < 0)
                                return IsEven(firstpositiveindex - 1) ? 0 : first;
                            else
                                return first;
                    }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Note that all not-null checks, overflows e.t.c. are checking before the function was called.

Update:
possible ways: sort and etc., loop through etc; Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your array only integers? In that case, there's nothing to do if the product is positive, and if its negative just find the largest (smallest in absolute value) negative integer and remove that. If you have to remove something even in the positive case, select the smallest positive integer.

Comment: You are doing a sort, which is O(n log n).  If all you need to do is find the min and max, just iterate once through the entire array to find them - O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Loop throw array is a more faster way than sorting. My fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *had no need* to **sort** the array, which requires **O(n*log(n))** complexity; 
you could have done with **O(n)** solution. That's why, IMHO, your code is *suboptimal*.
Possible implementation:

```
public int FindRequiredValue(int[] value) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
  else if (value.Length <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentException("Empty arrays can't be proceeded.", "value");

  // Algorithm:
  // if the array contains odd negative numbers print out the maximum among them:
  //   {-1, -2, -3, 4, 5} => -1
  // if the array contains even negative numbers print out the smallest non-negative one:
  //   {-1, -2, 4, 5} => 4
  // if array contains even negative numbers and no non-negative numbers print out the
  // smallest negative one 
  //   {-1, -2, -3, -4} => -4

  int max_Negative = 0;
  int min_Negative = 0;
  int min_NonNegative = -1;
  int negativeCount = 0;

  foreach (int v in value) {
    if (v < 0) {
      negativeCount += 1;

      if ((v > max_Negative) || (max_Negative == 0))
        max_Negative = v;

      if ((v < min_Negative) || (min_Negative == 0))
        min_Negative = v;  
    }
    else {
      if ((v < min_NonNegative) || (min_NonNegative == -1))
        min_NonNegative = v; 
    }  
  }

  if ((negativeCount % 2) == 1)
    return max_Negative;
  else if (min_NonNegative != -1)
    return min_NonNegative;
  else
    return min_Negative; 
}
```

Comment: Your idea is clear: Iterate is more fast way than sort. But if it's full solution, you're not handle zero's. You'll possible have situations with 1 zero, >1 zero and it's combinations with odd/even negatives count Anyway thank you!

Comment: @Pavel: Sorry, but I do handle zeros, that's why I've put "non-negative" instead of "positive". For instance {0, 1, 2, 3} => 0; {-1, -2, -3, 0} => -3; {-1, -2, 4, 5, 0} => 0; {-1, -2, 0, 0} => 0 etc.

Comment: Agree. I was too hastened. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this question you will either want to remove the smallest (in absolute value) negative integer if there are odd number of negative integers, or the smallest positive integer if there are even number of negative integers. (zero counts as positive)

So iterate through the array once and keep track of:
1. Lowest in absolute value negative integer.
2. Lowest in absolute value positive integer.
3. Number of negative integers.

After the iteration, remove accordingly.

Complexity: O(N) in time, and O(1) in space.

Comment: you're not handle zero's. But idea in common (looping through the array) is good.